# Is there a way to create a polar plot in Numbers?

Tags: numbers

I am trying to do a **polar plot**, or radar chart as excel calls them, for a report. I don't have excel, only **Numbers**, is there a way to do that type of plot with **Numbers**? I can't seem to find a way. The closest thing to a polar plot that I was able to create was a point cluster with the data transformed from polar to cartesian coordinates, but this doesn't center the axis at 0,0.

Answer (score 1):

An app called [Radars](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/radars/id840877886) on the Apple App Store generates polar plots for you to import to your Numbers documents. That's what it says in the description, I however have not tried it yet.